# How to know ATC Class 1-5 of a drug name in OpenFDA data

Tags: openfda, uses-of-open-data

I am trying to use OpenFDA open-source data so that I can know ATC Class 1-5 of a drug name and the disease it can be used to treat for?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid openFDA does not capture such information.